# ¿Por que mi consulta me muestra campos repetidos si en la base de datos no hay registros repetidos?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT concat(USU.USU_nombres,' ',USU.USU_apellidos) AS 'Nombre Completo', ODET.ODET_precioTotal AS 'Venta Total', CLI.CLI_nombres AS 'Nombre del Cliente' 
FROM clientes CLI INNER JOIN ordenes ORD 
    INNER JOIN ordenes_detalles ODET 
    INNER JOIN usuarios USU ON USU.USU_id=ORD.USU_id 
WHERE USU.USU_id=2
```

RESULTADO:

[image: Imagen de los resultados]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1):

Depende de lo que quieras lograr, veo 2 tipos de repeticiones, la primera ocasionada por la falta del `ON`en la instrucción `INNER JOIN ordenes_detalles ODET` lo cual genera un producto cartesiano.

La segunda repetición se da por que los valores de `Venta Total` son distintos entonces al unir tablas se no se sabe cual valor para esa columna elegir y se repite, para evitarlo deberías tomar una decision por ejemplo sumar los totales.

```
SUM(ODET.ODET_precioTotal) AS 'Venta Total'
```

Esto evitaria la repeticion de valores con contenidos distintos

Comment: es eso o que los inner join no tienen una clausula on y esta haciendo un producto cartesiano?

Comment: Cierto, ahora con la edicion que mejora el formato de snippet lo estoy viendo, editado, gracias.

Comment: No esta sumando ni agrupando por venta total. El problema no es eso. es de los joins incompletos.

Comment: Ahi lo actualice.

Comment: Joel, el valor de venta total no tiene nada que ver con el problema.. es solo por los joins... si el campo se llama telefono el problema seria el mismo...